# PHP function inside a if statements with logical operator

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I have a page with limited permissions. 
Only `'amministratore'` users can access to it and I would like to give the same permissions to `'dipendente'` users.

Here is the working code of the controller:

```
function userHasRole($role) {
    include 'db.inc.php';
    try
    {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utenti
            INNER JOIN utentiruoli ON utenti.id = utenteid
            INNER JOIN ruoli ON ruoloid = ruoli.id
            WHERE mail = :mail AND ruoli.id = :ruoloid";
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':mail', $_SESSION['mail']);
        $s->bindValue(':ruoloid', $role);
        $s->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Errore nella ricarca del ruolo utente.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    $row = $s->fetch();

    if ($row[0] > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
exit();
}   

if(!userHasRole('amministratore')){ 
    $error = 'Solo gli utenti registrati possono accedere a quest\'area';
    include '../accessonegato.html.php'; 
    exit();
}
```

I want also the `'dipendente'` user to be able to access the page but if I add the logical operations it seems not to work:

```
if(!userHasRole('amministratore') || !userHasRole('dipendente')){ 
    $error = 'Solo gli utenti registrati possono accedere a quest\'area';
    include '../accessonegato.html.php'; 
    exit();
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i hope, it should be a `&&` condition and not an `||`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the if statements logic, now it is:

((!userHasRole('amministratore') || !userHasRole('dipendente'))

it should be:

(!(userHasRole('amministratore') || userHasRole('dipendente'))

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is provide an error "if the user isn't an amministratore or a dipendente". This can be written as `if(!(userHasRole('amministratore') || userHasRole('dipendente'))`. If we distribute the negation according to De Morgan's laws, this can be rewritten as `if(!userHasRole('amministratore') && !userHasRole('dipendente'))`.

Whenever you distribute negation, you switch from `&&` to `||` or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  if (!userHasRole('amministratore') || !userHasRole('dipendente')) {
```

use

```
 if (!(userHasRole('amministratore') || userHasRole('dipendente'))) {
```

It's basically the same as checking one role, but now you're doing two.

Comment: it's working now. Thank you very much. Isn't possible to check two role in the other way?

Comment: Yes, I would check if the correct role is present, then show the protected content, and otherwise show the no-access message. It's slightly simpler and therefore more secure. Or you could change your `userHasRole()` function into `userHasOneOfTheseRoles()`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand very well. This code should check if the user has the amministratore role or dipendente: if(!userHasRole('amministratore') || !userHasRole('dipendente')).... why the if statements like this is not working?

Comment: You wrote "If an user is not an admin or not a "dipendente" then don't show the page. In other words with your code the user would have been an admin and a "dipendent" at the same time. But what you wanted was "if the user is not an admin AND not a "dipendent", then deny access

Comment: Your code reads like this: "if the user isn't a administrator or the user isn't a employee then show the no access message.". Now an administrator probably isn't an employee and visa versa. This means this condition will never be true.